# How do I add a new folder to gconf-editor?

Tags: gnome, thumbnails, gconf

I can't even figure out what these folders are called.  The things inside them are apparently called "keys".

How do I add another folder so that I can handle another file type that isn't listed?

[image: grr]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use `gconftool-2` in order to do this properly:

```
gconftool-2 --type=bool --set "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-custom/enable"  "false"
```

And to remove it:

```
gconftool-2 --unset --recursive-unset "/desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/application@x-custom"
```

Comment: Good!  Then I can use the graphical editor to add or modify keys, etc.

Comment: this sets a key but not creates a folder. ubuntu 11.04